# What is the derivation of the Shannon-Hartley theorem?

Tags: signal, bandwidth, signal-to-noise, capacity, information

[image]

I know by Hartley's theorem that information is proportional to bandwidth and time. The capacity corresponds to information and bandwidth is there. I don't get how the logarithmic part corresponds to time. Is there a derivation?

Comment: the information (in bits) transmitted via a channel is a transmission time (s) multiplied by a channel capacity (bit/s). The capacity is not proportional to transmission time, it can be a function of time, but with constant bandwidth and SNR the capacity is also constant.

Comment: the capacity defines the maximum transmission rate (data per time), not the information quantity

Comment: The log is just a proportionality, it doesn't relate to time and it doesn't have to. Why not? Because both bandwidth AND CAPACITY relate to time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: Bits are encoded as voltage not power. So \$C\varpropto\sqrt{P}\$

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive explanation of the Shannon-Hartley theorem was given as an answer to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82831) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged because they depend on the constancy of the link content